# Scene transition with CATransition in Cocos2D

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, transition

Currently I am trying to port a project of mine from `SpriteKit` to `Cocos2D`. And I'm stuck with the transition's. In `SpriteKit` I could use the `CATransition` to transition to another scene.

But I can't figure out how I could do that in `Cocos2D`. Or perhaps there is another way to achieve a similar effect in `Cocos2D`. The effect I'm going for is this "[pixelate](http://cl.ly/T4kb)" effect which is made with the [CATransition](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CATransition_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) class. If I could use that that would be awesome. If there is another way to achieve the same effect that is okay too.

Perhaps it is worth noting that I am using `Cocos2d` 3.

Answer (score 1):

According to your video you can push one scene to another scene using CCTransition in cocos2d with same effect. code as below

```
-(void)YourButtonToPush
{
   [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionTurnOffTiles transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[HelloWorldLayer scene]]];  
}
```

[image]

if you want to fast replacing to decrees transition time of the method.

Comment: It kinda does look like it. But it is not the same (in my example the pixels grow and shrink over time). Is there any way to achieve that. (Or use CATransition). With that I could make it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking at the source code for CCTransitionTurnOffTiles. You could then copy it and create your own transition with a few tweaks so it's closer to the pixilate transition from SpriteKit.

I haven't looked at the source for this but I suspect tweaking it to what you want should just be a case of changing which series of actions it uses on each block.